# MySQL except trying get all user that is online except one

Tags: mysql, except

How can I say in MySQL when I want to select all the typing and user that is online(1) except for one user with the id of 4? and I want the username of id= 4 not the typing

I tried NOT IN but I'm guessing it is not working for me.

```
SELECT username,typing FROM members WHERE status = 1 NOT IN (SELECT typing FROM members WHERE id =4)
```

http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/2313/typing.png

click the image for more info

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results?  Your description is not clear.

Comment: updated check the image

Comment: when you say "online(1)" do you mean "online (i.e. status=1)" ?  Just being sure as the image does not have a status column

Comment: yea it is a boolean, online is status =1

Comment: and what do you mean by "I want the username of id=4 not the typing" ? it sounds like you are contradicting yourself so please explain that part

Comment: if you look on the image I want everything on there except on that typing on cam . but I still want the cam username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT username, 
       (case when id <> 4 then typing end) as typing
FROM members
WHERE status = 1 or id = 4
```

Based on your image, I think you just want:

```
SELECT username, typing
FROM members
WHERE status = 1 and id <> 4
```

Comment: nope sorry, I want to select all the user and typing that is online which is status = 1 and except for typing where the id = 4

Comment: Saying the same thing as in your question doesn't make it any clearer. Can you show some sample data and the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a join like this:

```
SELECT username, typing FROM members members LEFT OUTER JOIN typing typing WHERE members.status = 1 AND typing.id <> 4
```